# Where can I save settings for widget?

Tags: jquery, css, xml, widget, webserver

I am developing a jquery widget for websites. I want to provide style settings options to website owners. Where can I save these settings other than my database??

Answer (score 0):

On the client you have option to save it in Cookies or [Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). But Local Storage is not supported by [all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage).

Comment: Thanks for your quick support and sorry if my question mislead you. I want to save the settings for every users of the website. If I am saving it in cookies that will be available only to that user right?

Comment: I thought that you need to provide unique settings for each user. Why database doesn't suit you?

Comment: Thanks again for your response.I can use database if there is no other option.